# Merge three boolean columns into one enumerated column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am migrating data from a DB with a table containing 3 boolean columns which are, in concept, mutually exclusive. eg:

```
| TypeA | TypeB | TypeC |
| 0     | 1     | 0     |
| 0     | 0     | 1     |
| 0     | 1     | 0     |
| 1     | 0     | 0     |
| 1     | 0     | 0     |
```

I need to merge these three booleans into a single column based on which of the 3 boolean columns is set to true. The result I'm after would look something like:

```
| Type |
| B    |
| C    |
| B    |
| A    |
| A    |
```

So far, I have come up with the following, however it feels a bit messy. Is there a better way?

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN TypeA= 1
   THEN 'A'
   ELSE
      CASE WHEN TypeB= 1
           THEN 'B'
           ELSE
              CASE WHEN TypeC= 1
                   THEN 'C'
              END
      END
END as Type
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Is there always one and only bit set in TypeA, TypeB, TypeC? In other words are the three types mutually exclusive? The examples given look that way.

Comment: @Shannon Severance Yeah, they're mutually exclusive. I mentioned that in the question, but only briefly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can stack your conditionals in a CASE statement like so

```
CASE
WHEN TypeA = 1 THEN 'A'
WHEN TypeB = 1 THEN 'B'
WHEN TypeC = 1 THEN 'C'
END as Type
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks much cleaner.

Comment: This is the best you should use.

Answer (score 2):

```
chr(65 + TypeB + 2*TypeC) as Type
```

---

Another solution:

```
decode(TypeB-TypeC, 0, 'A', 1, 'B', 'C') as Type
```

Comment: In this case I was just using A,B and C as examples. The real values will be unrelated strings. Very clever solution to the problem I gave though!

Comment: @AaronThomson - Another solution was appended for arbitrary strings.